# ruby - get command output, which is executing via ssh

Tags: ruby, ssh, terminal

I am new to ruby and I tried searching a lot but I cannot figure this out!

I need to execute this command:
I tried using Open3.popen, back-ticks but the output is not returned, it only returns for ssh command but I need the output of the hive query.

```
ssh -C -i key_rsa -l login_name server_name "/usr/bin/hive -i .hiverc -e \" some_query \"" > somefile.csv
```

How can I get the output & errors if any for hive query and ssh both?

Thanks in advance, please let me know as early as possible

Comment: Do you deliberately redirect your ouptut to a file with `> somefile.csv`?

Comment: yes, I deliberately do that

Comment: Just to double-check, after that command is run where do you expect ouptut to be? In the file you redirected to or in the stdout of the process you started?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify by ensuring that your query outputs to STDOUT first by logging into your target server and manually running the query. Next use single quotes around the query that follows the ssh command. Finally, add the redirect when you are sure the individual pieces are working:

```
    ssh -C -i key_rsa -l login_name server_name '/usr/bin/hive -i .hiverc -e " some_query "'
```

Comment: everything is working piece by piece, but still not getting the output

Comment: What is the outcome of: `ssh -C -i key_rsa -l login_name server_name 'ls'`

Comment: This is working, also I was able to get the previous command working,